# How to combine values of same items in a list?

Tags: python, list

```
list_end_result = [['walk', 10], ['games', 55], ['eat', 30], ['walk', 8], ['coding', 50], ['games', 55]

#Wanted_result: [['walk', 18], ['games', 110], ['eat', 30], ['coding', 50]]
```

Comment: if you want answers, you gotta include your own try as well.

Comment: Make a dictionary whose keys are the strings and values are the sums of the numbers associated with that string. `collections.defaultdict()` or `dict.setdefault()` are useful in this task.

Comment: To add to Barmar's comment, you can use a for loop to iterate over the initial list. Or better yet, use a dictionary to begin with rather than a list.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice OP cannot "use a dictionary to begin with", as their data contain duplicate keys.

Comment: @Grismar Sure they can. Instead of building a list then transforming it into a dictionary, they could just build a dictionary immediately using the same logic as building the dictionary from the list.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice sounds to me like you're saying "they could have just defined the data with all the answered pre-computed" - what would a dictionary with two entries for 'walk' look like, in your opinion?